# @media display:table-row doesnt work in IE9 rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this css file in my project

```
@media (min-width:$screen-sm) {
        display:table-row;
        position: static;
        height:50px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        border-width: 1px 0px;
        border-color:$ls-orange-1;
        border-style:solid;
        img.ls-decoration {
        }
      }
```

In Chrome and Firefox, it displays the table perfectly but in IE9, the height of each row is doubled. and not the size it requested.

I have tried the options for respond.js and cssmedia queries as follows

in my application page i added this

```
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="<%= params[:locale] ? params[:locale] : 'en' %>">

      <head>
        <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Loanstreet</title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css">
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/respond.min.js"></script>
 </head>
```

I also did the same for css mediaqueries and i added both files in my stylesheet folder but still to no avail.

Does anyone know how to go about this?  I am beginning to come to a conclusion that IE9 cannot support @media{display: table-row}

Thanks